# Should I use Force Tags or Default Tags

Tags: robotframework

I want to make use of Tags to note down the defect ID in test case.
So that I can run specific test case which defect occurred easily.

From user guide, example, there is Force Tags and Default Tags at settings. For my case, which one should I use? :

```
*** Settings ***
Force Tags      req-42
Default Tags    owner-john    smoke

*** Variables ***
${HOST}         10.0.1.42

*** Test Cases ***
No own tags
    [Documentation]    This test has tags owner-john, smoke and req-42.
    No Operation

With own tags
    [Documentation]    This test has tags not_ready, owner-mrx and req-42.
    [Tags]    owner-mrx    not_ready
    No Operation

Own tags with variables
    [Documentation]    This test has tags host-10.0.1.42 and req-42.
    [Tags]    host-${HOST}
    No Operation

Empty own tags
    [Documentation]    This test has only tag req-42.
    [Tags]
    No Operation

Set Tags and Remove Tags Keywords
    [Documentation]    This test has tags mytag and owner-john.
    Set Tags    mytag
    Remove Tags    smoke    req-*
```

My test cases is written in one file and setup as test suite, the defect appear at one of step for both cases, is this the correct setup?:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource            ../Resources/res.robot
Suite Setup         Suite Setup Suite
Test Setup          Test Setup
Suite Teardown      Test Teardown
Default Tags        Defect1


*** Test Cases ***
TC001-001-01
    [Tags]   Defect1
    Go To Page  1
    Go Back

TC001-001-02
    [Tags]   Defect1
    Go To Page  2
    Go Back
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want both your tests to get the tag `Defect1` then you can use either Force Tags in the Settings or [Tags] in the tests themselves.

`Default Tags` is not appropriate in that case because you would take the risk that some tests don't get the `Defect1` tag if some other tag is defined on the test.

So I would say the 2 possibilities are:

1. Use of `[Tags]` (handy because you see directly when looking at a test that it has the tag)

> ```
> *** Settings ***
> Resource            ../Resources/res.robot
> Suite Setup         Suite Setup Suite
> Test Setup          Test Setup
> Suite Teardown      Test Teardown
>
>
> *** Test Cases ***
> TC001-001-01
>     [Tags]   Defect1
>     Go To Page  1
>     Go Back
>
> TC001-001-02
>     [Tags]   Defect1
>     Go To Page  2
>     Go Back
> ```

2. Use of `[Force Tags]` (handy because you don't have to repeat the tag on each test)

> ```
> *** Settings ***
> Resource            ../Resources/res.robot
> Suite Setup         Suite Setup Suite
> Test Setup          Test Setup
> Suite Teardown      Test Teardown
> Force Tags          Defect1
>
>
> *** Test Cases ***
> TC001-001-01
>     Go To Page  1
>     Go Back
>
> TC001-001-02
>     Go To Page  2
>     Go Back
> ```